# MySQL not letting ' and " in Longtext

Tags: php, mysql, database

MySQL is not letting me use "s and 's with a context form I made for my site. All of the other fields sent to the database just fine, but the longtext one also makes an error if you use anything other than letters and numbers.

I have it at long text, not null.

I am trying to put mysql_real_escape_string()  in my code

Comment: What if you escape them with a backslash?

Comment: The form is for the users, I don't want them to have to type that backslash everytimg :( - Should I use varchar? I had troulbe with that too thouh

Comment: I understand that, I meant it as a test. And you shouldn't have any problems with varchar. I use it all the time.

Comment: It seems there was an error when posting your question, we cannot see your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized query then you don't have to worry about escaping special characters and it is safer too (ie against SQL injection attack).

Comment: I'm new to mysql so I'm not sure what you mean.. he is my query part: $sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(s_id, s_name, s_email, s_content)VALUES('$id', '$s_name', '$s_email', '$s_content')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

if($result2){
echo "Successful<BR>";

Comment: You have to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of "flat API", then you can use [PDOStatement->bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean?

Comment: @fealiuex The word "PDO" in my previous comment is link - click on it will take you to the PHP manual so you can read up about [PHP Data Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

find function in your programming language that escapes slashes and similar and apply it to your output before sending to database

Comment: Okay, the language is php... do you what I could use off hand?

Comment: I found this... how do I put it in with my query? string htmlspecialchars ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT [, string $charset [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )

Comment: try this one, it works on string layer http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() will work if used properly. Show us your PHP code (you can edit your question to add it) and we'll see what's wrong.

Comment: $sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(s_id, s_name, s_email, s_content)VALUES('$id', '$s_name', '$s_email', '$s_content')";
mysql_real_escape_string()
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

if($result2){
echo "Successful<BR>";

Answer (score 0):

This should work as proposed

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(s_id, s_name, s_email, s_content) VALUES(".$id.", '".mysql_real_escape_string($s_name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($s_email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($s_content)."')";
```

You should: Take advantage of prepared statements and if you don't do that escape ALWAYS!!! values that come from client input. If not your website can easily been hacked by script-kiddis that just test some sql-injections.

Comment: what is that + operator? PHP uses dot (.) for concatenation not +

Comment: to much c++ in the last time sorry

Comment: I switched it to periods, no luck

Comment: Currently i'm not at home and don'T have a php interpreter, what error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use prepared statements then the method you have adopted, the plus point of using Prepared Statements like PDO are, it will save you from attacks Such as MYSQL Injections and there are lot more, basically PDO is an inbuilt PHP class which lets you interact with your database at ease, plus it is very flexible, for example,

To establish a connection using PDO you just need to use one line of code, it is like initializing an object.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DATABASE,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
```

that's it, please note i have used Constant, you can replace it with you own.

now for example if you want to select something using PDO, you just need to write one line of code.

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT id,name FROM table');
//Query is executed in the above code, and when you want to retrieve the value you just need another line of code.
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

that's it, now you have an array $result which holds all the retrieved value. isn't it very simple and easy to use?

to get you started with using PDO here take a look at this tutorial in [net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)
they have explained it very well.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but will this allow for ' and " ?

Comment: yes of course it should work but if you want to store special symbols like single quotes or double quotes then you should escape it using `addslashes();` for example let's say you want store a string `$string = 'I'm google+, Facebook's new competitor'` then before inserting it directly to the database you need to use the above function, sot that special symbols like that are escaped.

Comment: Here, have a look at this article, this may give you a clear picture on how strings manipulation works in PHP http://v1.jeroenmulder.com/weblog/2005/04/php_single_and_double_quotes.php